# MacBook Pro won't boot

Tags: startup, install

I have a Macbook Pro 8.2, Intel i7, 4 GB of RAM and 500 GB HDD.

While working with some apps open in background, the screen suddenly went blank and music looped. In panic I pushed the power button to shut the Mac down. After a while, I tried to boot. It paused half way and the screen turned to grey but didn't shut down for half hour. I decided to turn it off.

I was searching and found some troubleshoot for my problems. I tried to reset PRAM and SMC. I tried to replace Battery, RAM and HDD, then reset PRAM and SMC. Neither worked.

I tried to boot to Recovery Mode, but the Recovery HD can't be found on my HDD. Then I tired to boot to Internet Recovery Mode and after download finished, it turned grey for half hour or more and finally shut down.

I tried to boot from DVD by holding C which wasn't working. On startup manager, I found my primary startup disk that failed to boot, but it can't find the disk.

Please help and guide me to backup my files and install clean os x offline or online.

Comment: In my experience - tho this hasn't happened for a long time - this behavior means the logic board is going bad, for which there is only replacement. Have you got an external portable USB drive to back up to now? Try SuperDuper for that backup.

Comment: If this latest edit is an *answer* to the original question, please create a separate *answer* - don't edit the the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad RAM slot.  I had a similar issue with that and garbled screen.  It's still possible to run it with a single stick of memory if one slot is bad.

Answer (score 1):

> **Update**
>
> My Macbook Pro already fix by Apple Authorized Service Provider and
>   they put my MBP to [MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program for Video
>   Issues](http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/).
>
> Before they take my MBP, I have to make sure that all of my data safe.
>   They give me a firewire/Lan cable to access all of my data inside of
>   it and I have to delete some Private/Sensitive data and Backup all of
>   my "Work In Progress Files". Glad everything goes fine and smooth. And
>   the important things is I don't spend any peny for this repair, except
>   my personal expense to go there.

**Symptoms**
When working with Application that using most of GPU; Photoshop, InDesign, Google Maps, Safari, etc. Or using external display plugged for long time with heavy application. Then the display will sudenly blank (white or black), then showing up with horizontal lines like old TV. After that happen for minutes or less, then system freeze (All you gonna do is force shutdown). Boot up the MBP with blank grey or system load on half or 3/4. This is permanent failure with different restart procedures, and each case write bellow:

**Normal startup**: Your computer will boot, show the Apple logo and pinwheel, stuck on half way or 3/4 of system progress, and then go to a white/grayish screen and remain there (no warning text, just a plain/blank). You must force reboot (hold the power button down, again).

- **Safe mode startup**: While booting the computer hold the Shift key
  until you see the Apple logo and system progress. About 60% of the
  way through the progress indicator your computer will go to a blue
  screen with horizontal lines. Note: In some case you can't boot to
  Safe Mode.
- **Recovery mode startup**: While booting hold down Command + R. You
  should get to a screen that shows the option of which drive to boot
  from. Any selection will result in the same blue screen with
  horizontal lines as in the Safe mode startup. Note: In some case you
  can't boot to Recovery Mode.
- **Console mode startup**: While booting hold down Command + S to boot in
  console mode. You might see distorted colors in your console (mine
  had blue lines, some have had red lines). We'll get back to how to
  use this mode to get your computer somewhat functional, but for now
  type sudo shutdown -h now to shutdown, or sudo reboot. Note: In some
  case you can't boot to Console Mode.

**Early Symptoms Include**:
 - Overheating when running graphics-intensive web sites, which causes
   the fans to loudly run.
 - Random crashes with different solid-screen-colors showing up (black,
   blue, gray).
 - Random graphics glitches.
 - Graphics distortions when plugging in an external monitor.

**The Issue(s)**
The issue is all about the heat inside your MBP. The AMD Radeon cards released with this MBP bring something wrong and easily to over heat, then affected to all the hardware (thanks god it's not blow the logic board).

**Fortunately**
In some case you were far away from Apple Authorized Service Provider.
Here are the first thing you can (if you can) do:

> Disclaimer: Some users have stated they have trouble reversing this
>   fix after performing it. I cannot help you if you have trouble with
>   this, so proceed at your own risk.

1. If you can boot to Console Mode (Click Power button while holding
   Command + S), then continue with this solution. If you can't, stop
   right there and bring your MBP to Apple Authorized Service Provider.
2. Mount the Hard Driver.

   > `-uw /`
3. Create backup from the root directory (you are now).

   > `mkdir /Users/your_user_name/AMDDriverBackup`
4. Then move all of this files.

   > `mv /System/Library/Extensions/ATI* /Users/your_user_name/AMDDriverBackup`
   >
   > `mv /System/Library/Extensions/AMD* /Users/your_user_name/AMDDriverBackup`
5. Now try to reboot from Console Mode

   > `sudo reboot`

If you can make it or your MBP can make it. From now on you should be able to revive your MBP to do basic things.

For more instructions you can read an article, [2011 Macbook Pro Graphics Card Failure](https://people.cam.cornell.edu/~zc227/extras/early2011mbp_graphics.html) by Zach Clawson